# Generating list of random vectors of random lengths

Tags: r, simulation, vectorization

Suppose I have a vector of 'frequencies', like

`freq <- rpois(N, lambda)`

For each of the `N` simulation runs, I want to create a random vector of length `freq[i]` with uniform(0,1) distribution.

I naively try `runif(freq, 0, 1)`, but R takes that to be `runif(length(freq),0,1)`

To maximize performance, I want to vectorize the code as much as possible. What do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`lapply()` will perform the task for each frequency.

```
freq <- rpois(N, lambda)
lapply(freq, runif)
```